# Display integers with max precision but fixed length in d3 (use SI notation)

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm using d3 to display the number of persons in a group. Based on how the user filter, it can be more than 100k or a single digit number

I tried **d3.format(".2s")**, and it works well most of the time, but I have two problems:

- when the number is <10, it displays 8​**.0**, I would need to display 8
- when the number is between 100 and 999, it drops the last digit, so 442 persons are displayed as 44**0**

My ideal format function would display the integer with the maximum precision possible in a fixed maximum number of characters/numbers. so if I want to limit the display to 3 numbers/4 chars, it would:

- display the number up to 999
- display 1k from 1000 to 1049
- display 1.1k from 1050 to 1099
- display 123k from 123'000 to 123'499
- ...

is there a way to specify a maximum display size instead of a specific precision?

(and before any mathematician burns me to have such a cavalier attitude to precision, the number display is to give an indication, the users always have an option to see the real number, without any loss of precision ;)

Comment: Funnily enough, you could have saved a lot of words, asking just *"I want a number format just like the one S.O. uses to display the reputation points"*.

Comment: Ooh, this is what I want indeed, please, santa, please ;)

Comment: Ops, I'm wrong: S.O. starts using S.I. only after 10000 points. I could swear it was after 1000...

Comment: It feels more natural to have the cut off at 1k than 10k, but given that "1.3k" is the same length as 1328, it might be a smarter display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by specifying custom formatting function. If I understand you correctly, it should look like this:

```
function customFormat(value) {
    var formattedValue = value;

  if (value > 999 && value < 100000) {
    if (value % 1000 < 50) {
        formattedValue = d3.format('.0s')(value);
    } else {
        formattedValue = d3.format('.2s')(value);
    }
  } else if (value >= 100000) {
    formattedValue = d3.format('.3s')(value);
  }

    return formattedValue;
}
```

Little demo how it works:

```js
var svgOne = d3.select("#scale-one")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)");

var svgTwo = d3.select("#scale-two")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)");
    
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([0,490])
  .domain([0,2000]);

function customFormat(value) {
 var formattedValue = value;
  
  if (value > 999 && value < 100000) {
    if (value % 1000 < 50) {
     formattedValue = d3.format('.0s')(value);
    } else {
     formattedValue = d3.format('.2s')(value);
    }
  } else if (value >= 100000) {
    formattedValue = d3.format('.3s')(value);
  }
  
 return formattedValue;
}

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
 .tickValues([8, 777, 1049, 1750])
  .tickFormat(customFormat);

var xLargeNumbers = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([0,490])
  .domain([123000, 126000]);
  
var xAxisLargeNumbers = d3.axisBottom(xLargeNumbers)
 .tickValues([123499, 123999])
  .tickFormat(customFormat);
  
svgOne.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,5)")
    .call(xAxis);

svgTwo.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,5)")
    .call(xAxisLargeNumbers);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div>Ticks: [8, 777, 1049, 1750] -</div>
<div id="scale-one"></div>
<div>Ticks: [123499, 123999] -</div>
<div id="scale-two"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to answer perfectly indeed Mikhail, I was hoping there is a generic d3.formatInt or something... because now the hard part: how to name that beauty ;). i'm checking and coming back to SO later today

Comment: Good answer, but this could be way shorter: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo5qLwpx/